# Replace iMovie Source Clip

Tags: video, imovie

I am working on a iMovie 09 project which contains many small video clips, extracted from the a long source clip.

After noticing a glitch with the original, i tried fix it by replacing the source clip. However, in iMovie, i can only replace one clip extract at a time. Is there anyway that i can replace the source clip, and thus, update all the extracted clips?

Answer (score 0):

The clips used in iMovie are actually rendered optimized-for-editing "miniclips", stored as thumbnails in your computer. If you replace the source file, but continue going on as per normal, the video should render properly at the end.

With the new QuickTime X and it's trimming function, what you might want to do is to trim the okay source clip (make a copy first) to the affected parts, and re-import it.